# How to insert a list into a list at a specific location?

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I have a list as following

```
List_a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

I want to insert `[0, 3]` into index `1`.

How it should look like:

```
New_List_a = [1, [0,3], 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thats not actually an insert ...

Comment: It looks like you are *replacing* the element at index `1`, not inserting anything. It's also unclear if you're modifying an existing list or creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic approach is

```
List_a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
# New_List_a = [1, [0,3], 0, 0, 1, 1]
l=[]
l.append(List_a[1])

for i in range(0,len(List_a)):
    if(i==1): # real signature unknown
        l.append(3)
        List_a[i]=l
        break
```

or you can also do this

```
   List_a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
   List_a[1] = [List_a[1], 3]     
   print(List_a)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
List_a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
List_a[1] = [List_a[1], 3]
print(List_a)  # [1, [0, 3], 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(list1, index, value):
     list1[index] = [List1[index], value]
     return list1
```